# Apply Object In Function

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of `this.apply(obj);` when function is invoked. For example this code.

```
    Function.prototype.blio = function (a) {
        this.hurka = 'hurka';
        var obj = {};
        this.apply(obj); // what exactly happens here ?
    }
```

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it out!

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

foo(); // logs window
console.log(foo.hurka); // undefined
foo.blio(); // logs {}
console.log(foo.hurka); // "hurka"
```

But wait, `foo.blio` invoked `foo`!
Therefore, when invoked as `foo.blio()`

- `this` in `blio` is `foo`
- `this.apply` is equivalent to `foo.apply`
- `this` inside `foo` was set to `{}` through the `apply`

You can read more on [`Function.prototype.apply` on MDN docs **here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Ok but what happens on this row where this.apply(obj); is defined. What means this.apply(...) inside of function ?